# How can I restrict access to visitors in a SP Online Modern Communication Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, communication-site

Basically we don't want Visitors to have access to the Site Contents page and also Site usage.

I've tried changing the permission from **Read** to **Restricted Read** but then the user can't even see the home page (it's a modern page), it gets a Sorry, you don't have access.

Is this possible to accomplish in Communication Site?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the site contents page is application page. You could try to uncheck the option View application pages for the read permission level.

[image]

Comment: I will give that a try. I thought application pages were ALL the modern pages, but maybe I am wrong